# PAYPAL integration: Invoice

Tags: paypal

In our business model our clients would need to send us an invoice i.e. they are sellers and we the merchant is going to be the buyer. However, I couldn't find a way to get the list of unpaid invoices from Paypal via asp.net API. I have some questions.

1. We are thinking of asking the client to submit our transaction identifier in the memo field when they generate the invoice and then using e-mail parsing to fuzzy match it. Is there any other way to match it?
2. Is there a way to give the client our merchant dedicated invoice generating form inside of PayPal. So, when the client login into his or her account and wants to generate and send us an invoice they see our companies dedicated form filled up with the details about the transaction that they then send it via PayPal.
3. Is there a way to create all the invoice details so the client just has to login and the invoice will be ready for them to send with their approval.

Thank you,
Raj

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You've asked more than one questions It is best to ask one specific question, so you can get focused answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Have you looked at the [Invoicing API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/IntroInvoiceAPI/)?  There are a number of different ways you could set this sort of thing up.  You did mention it, but then I'm not sure why you're struggling to get done what you're trying to do, because you could handle it however you need using the API.